# Erro no envio de pacote com scapy

Tags: python-3.x

Galera estou fazendo o curso Python para Hackers, mas me deparei com um problema na aula sobre COMO CRIAR SEU PRIMEIRO PACOTE. Eu consigo criar o pacote, mas não consigo enviar através do sr(), sr1(), srloop(), srloop1(), etc.. Eu sempre me deparo com esse erro aqui:

```
fail 1: IP / TCP 192.168.15.8:ftp_data > 192.168.15.8:http S
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser e como posso resolver? Já pesquisei pela internet mas não consegui encontrar a solução (na verdade não consegui achar alguém que tenha tido este problema)

Obs: Scapy está instalado corretamente, já executei o python como sudo e esses foram os comandos que executei para criar e enviar meu pacote:

```
from scapy.all import *
ip = IP(dst="192.168.15.8")
tcp = TCP(dport=80)
pkt = ip/tcp
sr(pkt)
```

Quando rodo estes comandos só aparece um bocado de pontinhos, aí eu uso o `srloop()` pra ver o que aconteceu, e quando rodo este comando, a saída que tenho é o erro que apresentei. Se alguém tiver ideia do que pode ser e como resolver, por favor me ajudem.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido. Meu roteador trabalha com o ip diferente desse, mas quando executo comandos para verificar o ip da conexão, este é o ip que aparece.